# Jquery - creating dynamically ul with only first element having class attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I have to create a ul appending it to a div dynamically using jquery , here is the example code I am referring https://github.com/linslin/pagingSlider , The code is so,

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="footer-menu myPageContainerClass">
        <ul class="pager clearfix">
            <li class="active"></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
</div>
```

I am able to create a list

```
var parentwrapper = $("<div/>").attr('id', 'wrapper');
var pointerDiv = $("<div/>").addClass("footer-menu myPageContainerClass");
var cList = $('<ul></ul>').addClass("pager clearfix");
var pointerList = $('<li></li>').append('<li></li>').append('<li></li>').append('<li></li>')
.appendTo(cList);


$(pointerDiv).append(pointerList);

var myFinalVar = $(parentwrapper).append(pointerDiv);
$(myFinalVar).appendTo('body');
```

but the class attribute are not reflecting in it,
what did I miss ? I'm new to JQuery Cordova applications

Comment: You're not appending `cList` - change `$(pointerDiv).append(pointerList);` to `$(pointerDiv).append(cList);` - so it's not adding the "pager" class because there's no `ul` in the output

Comment: You also don't need to "double-dip" your jquery objects:  you're effectively doing `$($("<div>"))`

Comment: Also: `.append()` puts inside, so you're getting `<li><li></li><li></li><li></li></li>` (easier to see if you just look at the output in the browser)

Comment: Thank you @freedomn-m, your suggestions solved my problem. Thanks a lot.